# @InitBinder for spring mvc

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, binding

I have similar problem with the man from 
[this post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/118063-spring-3-mvc-nested-form-select-problem)

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
    // we configure custom PropertyEditor for the given type and property
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Department.class, new DepartmentEditor());
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/new" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEmployee(
        @ModelAttribute @Valid Employee employee,
        BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model ) {
```

The model Employee has one variable from another model the Department, OneToOne connection with hibernate

In the form i select the department but when i submit i have some errors...

```
<form:select path="department" id="department">
        <form:options items="${departments}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"></form:options>
</form:select>



message : Field error in object 'employee' on field 'department': rejected value [1]; codes [methodInvocation.employee.department,methodInvocation.department,methodInvocation.com.websystique.springmvc.model.Department,methodInvocation]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [employee.department,department]; arguments []; default message [department]]; default message [Property 'department' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] --
```

field 'department': rejected value [1](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/118063-spring-3-mvc-nested-form-select-problem)    is the id number from dropdown selection

```
@Component
public class DepartmentEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

    @Autowired
    DepartmentService depService;

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        return super.getAsText();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if(value.isEmpty()){
            try {
                Department dep = depService.findById(Integer.parseInt(value));
                if (null!=dep) {
                    setValue(dep);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Binding error. Cannot find userAccount with id  ["+value+"]");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Binding error. Invalid id: " + value);
            }
        } else {
            setValue(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but in your setAsText method, you do not need to find your department. Instead of Department dep = depService.findById(Integer.parseInt(value));, could you try this: Department dep = new Department(); dep.setId(Long.parseLong(text)); setValue(dep);

Comment: in logs i found this
2015-07-28 15:54:08 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [zzzzzz]

this mean that initbinder bind wrong attitude from request... it takes an input not the select.... it has to take a number from select

Comment: Did you take this log after change what I said, or this log was given before?

Comment: i user Department dep = new Department();  dep.setId(Integer.parseInt(value));       and         dep = depService.findById(Integer.parseInt(value));    but and the two have the same error.... initbinder takes the wrong input from view.....

Comment: as you can see i use @Autowired
 DepartmentService depService; for some reason the autowire doesnt work.... do you have any solution

Comment: I am trying to come up with a solution. I used this source https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/using-initbinder-in-spring-3-controller/ before suggesting you. But apperantly it did not work.

Comment: my friend thank you very much for your time.... the solution is to create a construcor with arguement the service you want and change the dao from persist to saveOrUpdate method....

Comment: Perfect. Could you also answer your own question with codes in the new post and select it as a correct answer. Therefore people having similar problem can easily find solution :)

Answer (score 0):

> AbstractDao

```
public void persist(T entity) {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
}
```

> Controller

```
@Autowired
DepartmentService depService;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
    LOGGER.info("@InitBinder " + request);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Department.class, new DepartmentEditor(depService));
}
```

> DepartmentEditor

```
@Override
public void setAsText(String value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    LOGGER.info("value = " + value);
    if(!value.isEmpty()){
        Department department;
        try {
            LOGGER.info("value_2 = " + value);
            department = depService.findById(new Integer(value));
            LOGGER.info("value_3 = " + department);
            if (null!=department) {
                setValue(department);
            } else {
                setValue(department);
                LOGGER.info("Error ", new IllegalArgumentException("Binding error. Cannot find userAccount with id  ["+value+"]"));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            LOGGER.info("This is Error message ", e);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Binding error. Invalid id: " + value);
        }
    } else {
        setValue(null);
    }
}
```